# Writing an async webservice with BeginExecuteNonQuery?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asynchronous

I have a sql stored proc that will kick off a bulk insert and I don't need my webservice to be hung up, waiting for a response. My question is this: how would I implement BeginExecuteNonQuery in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could get you started:

```
private void ExecuteCommandAsync(string sql)
{
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectString + "Async=true;");
   SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = sql;
   conn.Open();
   cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery(new AsyncCallback(AsyncCommandCompletionCallback), cmd);
}

private void AsyncCommandCompletionCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
   SqlCommand cmd = null;
   try
   {
       cmd = (SqlCommand)result.AsyncState;
       cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);

       // Do some more work here...
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       // Handle errors here
   }
   finally
   {
       cmd.Connection.Close();
       cmd.Dispose();
   }
}
```